# How to Contol the RPM of a Micro Metal Gearmotor with Encoders (Pololu) using PID?

Tags: arduino, pid, quadrature-encoder

I use the PID algorithm to control the RPM of a micro Gearmotor.  My motor and encoder specifications are given below.

Motor: https://www.pololu.com/product/2378 - 6V 29.86:1 gear ratio - please kindly note that I'm using a 9V battery.
Encoder: https://www.pololu.com/product/4760 - 12 counts per revolution of the motor shaft

Also, using Arduino Mega MCU, and this is my sketch:

```
#include <util/atomic.h> // For the ATOMIC_BLOCK macro

#define ENCA 3 // YELLOW
#define ENCB 2 // WHITE
#define PWM 5
#define IN2 6
#define IN1 7


volatile int pos_i = 0; // specify posi as volatile: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/variable-scope-qualifiers/volatile/
long prevT = 0;
int posPrev = 0; 

volatile float velocity_i = 0;
volatile long prevT_i = 0;

float v1Filt = 0;
float v1Prev = 0;
float v2Filt = 0;
float v2Prev = 0;

float eintegral = 0;
float eprev = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(ENCA,INPUT);
  pinMode(ENCB,INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(ENCA),readEncoder,RISING);
  
  pinMode(PWM,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IN1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IN2,OUTPUT);
  
}

void setMotor(int dir, int pwmVal, int pwm, int in1, int in2){
  analogWrite(pwm,pwmVal);
  if(dir == 1){
    digitalWrite(in1,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(in2,LOW);
  }
  else if(dir == -1){
    digitalWrite(in1,LOW);
    digitalWrite(in2,HIGH);
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(in1,LOW);
    digitalWrite(in2,LOW);
  }  
}


void loop() {


  int pos = 0;
  float velocity2 = 0;
  ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE){
    pos = pos_i;
    velocity2 = velocity_i;
  }

  long currT = micros();
  float deltaT = ((float) (currT-prevT))/1.0e6;
  float velocity1 = (pos - posPrev)/deltaT;
  posPrev = pos;
  prevT = currT;

  float v1 = velocity1 / 89.58  * 60.0;
  float v2 = velocity2 / 89.58  * 60.0;

  // Low-pass filter (25 Hz cutoff)
  v1Filt = 0.854*v1Filt + 0.0728*v1 + 0.0728*v1Prev;
  v1Prev = v1;
  v2Filt = 0.854*v2Filt + 0.0728*v2 + 0.0728*v2Prev;
  v2Prev = v2;

  float vt = 60;

  float kp = 2.0;
  float ki = 4.5;
  float kd = 0.0;
  
  float e = vt - v1Filt;
  eintegral = eintegral + e*deltaT;

  float dedt = (e-eprev)/(deltaT);
  
  float u = kp*e + ki*eintegral;

  // Set the motor speed and direction
  int dir = 1;
  if (u<0){
    dir = -1;
  }
  int pwr = (int) fabs(u);
  if(pwr > 255){
    pwr = 255;
  }
  setMotor(dir,pwr,PWM,IN1,IN2);
  eprev = e;
  
  
  Serial.print(vt);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(v1Filt);
  Serial.println();
  delay(1);
  
}

void readEncoder(){
  // Read encoder B when ENCA rises
  int b = digitalRead(ENCB);
  int increment = 0;
  if(b>0){
    // If B is high, increment forward
    increment = 1;
  }
  else{
    // Otherwise, increment backward
    increment = -1;
  }
  pos_i = pos_i + increment;

  // Compute velocity with method 2
  long currT = micros();
  float deltaT = ((float) (currT - prevT_i))/1.0e6;
  velocity_i = increment/deltaT;
  prevT_i = currT;
}
```

However, the motor RPM is rapidly oscillating, and it is not reaching the desired RPM level. I tried several Kp and Ki values, but still no luck.

Any help regarding this issue is highly appreciated.

Best regards,
Upul

Comment: I hope your 9V battery is not [the kind with snap connectors on top](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-volt_battery). Although the voltage seems generous, such batteries cannot supply enough current to operate your motor. Consider using four AA cells until you have debugged the software/controls.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to PID control is a constant step controller.  It's a controller that looks at the error and then just adds (or subtracts) a constant amount (usually very small).  It's very easy to implement and very intuitive.  However, it is slow to reach the desired velocity.  This can be mitigated with a feed forward mechanism; when starting from 'stopped' calculate the initial control value (throttle pwm value) based on measured values for stall throttle (the throttle (pwm value) below which the motor will not turn; so this also corresponds to the minimum possible non-zero velocity).  Given the target velocity, you can do a linear interpolation between min and max velocity to estimate the feed forward value for throttle.  Then the constant step controller will converge quickly from a standing start.  If there is a large perturbation while moving it will still respond slowly.

This differential drive robot uses a feed forward constant step controller for speed control and a constant step controller for heading control during goal to goal behavior.  https://github.com/Ezward/Esp32CameraRover2  Speed control is here https://github.com/Ezward/Esp32CameraRover2/blob/3cb95bc326873d1e354887132699924332c0c7e8/src/wheel/drive_wheel.cpp#L323, kinematic pose estimation is here https://github.com/Ezward/Esp32CameraRover2/blob/3cb95bc326873d1e354887132699924332c0c7e8/src/rover/rover.cpp#L313, and heading controller is here https://github.com/Ezward/Esp32CameraRover2/blob/3cb95bc326873d1e354887132699924332c0c7e8/src/rover/goto_goal.cpp#L333  Here an example of it in operation https://youtu.be/TjE9ceNOTJE